# Promise which executes http.get returns as "pending"

Tags: node.js, promise

I build an array of promises. Some promises require making http.get() before resolving. Others resolve without this. I push all promises to an array and then iterate. The promises including http.get() are still pending.

I've tried doing promise.all. I've tried replacing the http.get() with resolve(200). This always executes the promise.

```
const https = require('https');
const http = require('http');
let promises = [];

exports.RegisterHTTPDependency = function(url, name, severity) {
  let promise = [];
  let pr = GeneratePromise(url);
  promise.push(pr, name, severity)
  promises.push(promise)
}

exports.Check = function() {
  let results = {};
  for (let i = 0; i < promises.length; i++) {
    const check = promises[i];
    console.log('promise: ', check[0]) // this returns "Promise { <pending> }" or 20, 
    // depending on if the resolve(20) is included in GeneratePromise
  }
}

let GeneratePromise = function(url){
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      // resolve(20) // if I include this code, it returns 20
      http.get(url, (resp) => {
        let data = '';
        resp.on('data', (chunk) => {
          data += chunk;
        });
        resp.on('end', () => {
          resolve(resp.statusCode); // this promise does come back <pending>
        });
      }).on("error", (err) => {
        reject(err);
      });
    });
}
```

The value 20 is a return value. I want the resp.statusCode to be a return value as well, instead of pending.

Comment: what do you get when you `console.log(resp)`?

Comment: resp.statusCode prints 200

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since from `GeneratePromise()`, it is indeed returning a `200`. The reason why you get a pending is where this function is called did not wait for the promise to resolve when you call the `GeneratePromise()` function.

In short, a promise can have 3 stages (`pending`, `fulfilled`, `rejected`). When you output the promise, it is still pending(not yet `resolved` or `rejected`)

What you can do is to use the `async`, `await` keywords to instruct the program to block the execution until the promise resolve, turning the promise from `pending` stage to `fulfiled`.

```
exports.RegisterHTTPDependency = async function(url, name, severity) {
  let promise = [];
  let pr = await GeneratePromise(url);
  promise.push(pr, name, severity)
  promises.push(promise)
}
```

Comment: so when does the `get` request truly get fired? I'm seeing that this works, but I need to pause 3 seconds before running the `Check` function, which iterates over promises. If I don't pause, no promises are registered. It doesn't appear as though this is truly pausing or making everything synchronous.

Comment: The suggested modification only makes the code inside `RegisterHTTPDependency()` function synchronous. However, if you call `Check()` right after `RegisterHTTPDependency()` in a non-blocking way, the result from `RegisterHTTPDependency()` is not yet resolved.

Comment: The easiest way to fix the problem is to turn `RegisterHTTPDependency()` into a async function and `await` it before you call the check, but refactoring the structure of the code should be a better solution. Currently, `RegisterHTTPDependency()` creates a side-effect and the `Check()` checks the side-effect made. It is better not to have them operate using side effect.

Comment: that makes a lot of sense. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @bravinator932421 you are welcome. Please mark the answer as correct if the answer solves your problem, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think if you have an array of promises the correct way to "wait" for them to resolve would be with Promise.all().

```
Promise.all(promisesArray)
  .then(result => {
    // will execute when every promise has been fulfilled
    // result is an array of the values returned by your promises.
  })
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Promise/all